# Change Google Account display?

Tags: gmail, google-account

My first name is `Lacto` and last name `Mah`.

My Gmail is `lacto.mah@gmail.com`.

But why does Google keep showing me: `lactomah@gmail.com`?

It shows me that one when I have logged in into gmail.com/google.com.
Is it a way to change it back to `lacto.mah@gmail.com`?

Comment: Btw its not a good idea to publicly post your email address. (unless that's not really your email address).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Google accounts ignores all periods (it's a "feature").  In other words, you can put a period anywhere in your name, and use it for an email address.
P.S.  here's some more interesting info about it: http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/09/gmail-easter-eggs-dot-blindess-email.html